# Web Application table

Tags: c#, html, razor-pages

I am working on a Web Application project and in my Model I have two lists:

```
 public IEnumerable<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }
 public List<int> AnotherInfo { get; set; }
```

In my view model I am displaying the items of the Employee list as a table:

```
 @foreach (var employee in Model.EmployeeList)
  {
     <tr>
         <td>@employee.Names</td>
         <td>@employee.Age</td>
         <td>@@employee.Address</td>               
     </tr>
 }
```

As a result I have a table with 3 columns: Name, Age and Address.

Now I want to have a fourth column where to display the second list: AnotherInfo

Is there any way I can make this fourth column to be on the same row as the others?

Comment: How is the data in AnotherInfo related to an employee? Do you want to display the entire list in the column or just a value from the list?

Comment: ... you add a `<th>` for the header and a `<td>` for the data? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to parse `EmployeeList` to a list and make a loop with `for` loop, like this:

```
public List<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }
public List<int> AnotherInfo { get; set; }

@for (var index = 0; index < EmployeeList.Count; index++)
{
    var employee = EmployeeList[index];
    var info = AnotherInfo[index];
    <tr>
        <td>@employee.Names</td>
        <td>@employee.Age</td>
        <td>@employee.Address</td>               
        <td>@info</td>
    </tr>
}
```

---

**Update:**

If you cannot change the type of `EmployeeList`, you can still make a copy list based on it:

```
List<Employee> list = EmployeeList.ToList();
// or
// var list = EmployeeList.ToList();
```

Then, you try the solution above.

Comment: this assumes that the two collections are the same size. may just need to clarify if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Retic Yes, I imagine that they have the same size.

Comment: Yes they have the same size and this looks like what I want but the problem is that the EmployeeList is of type IEnumerable so I can't access it by index

Comment: @gameloverr2 call .toList() on the IEnumberable and then pass the resulting list to the page model.